# Pattern design on cloth

Tags: animation

I'm not getting anywhere with my cloth design animation.

I have a city idea planned out for my animation. And I want banners to be seen on a few of the buildings with a dragon on the banner in gold.

Every time I run the animation to see how it turned out, the design just falls off. I used a .svg model which I then converted to a mesh.

From there I joined the 2 meshes together. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about using an image texture on the banner? You can convert your svg to an image

Comment: I'll see if that works

Comment: It worked. I'm so glad it finally worked